# Cancel Gmail auto save of draft programmatically

Tags: google-chrome-extension, gmail, gmail-api, inboxsdk

I need to encrypt the real message that user write in compose mode in Gmail , so I created a Chrome extension that creates another button of 'secure send' in compose window ( I am using [gmail.js](https://github.com/KartikTalwar/gmail.js/tree/master) library and [InboxSdk](https://www.inboxsdk.com/) library ). The problem is that when user write a new message a draft save automatically every time user keep writing and the real message actually not secure.

I think about update every time the draft when user change the content via [Gmail API Users.drafts: update](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/drafts/update) but the problem that also here it's save for a while to Google and I don't want it.

Is there some option to cancel the auto save of the draft? Then maybe I somehow try to save the draft by myself.. I don't see anything about this in the gmail.js and InboxSDK library's and also in the rest of my research...

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK [[image]gmail-api](/questions/tagged/gmail-api) hasn't a method to block the Gmail UI draft message autosave. In an scenario like the one described on the question, I think that the best is to avoid the use of the Gmail UI to compose new messages.

Anyway, Gmail draft autosave on the UI is done by using AJAX. I suggest you to try to find out which request sends the body of the draft messages and block it only while your extension users writes something to be encrypted.

Comment: Thanks for your answer . I look at javaScript client-side but I am not find any option to disable it?you sure that exist something that I could cancel it? And ,  if I not use gmail UI to compose new messages so what ? I need to create my own compose window and to inject it via the DOM ? it's sounds me complicated to create all Gmail compose window functionality......

Comment: @OriEng: I edited my answer. I'm sorry, I'm not able to give something more specific at this time.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. It's good idea but I don't know how to find this event , I try to cancel all keyboard events but it's not help , how could I find and to cancel the auto save event?. In gmail.js library I found event that fired when a draft is saved , but it's fired just after it's already saved to google and not before. I don't find any another information anywhere about this unfortunately.

Comment: I'm not familiar with gmail.js library and I started to checkout [tag:gmail] ant [tag:gmail-api] very recently, so I don't know it gmail.js library could help for this specific question. Try searching this site about [how to block ajax requests and [tag:google-chrome-extension]]